# need help using quotes in href with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help writing a link using js.

This is what I have but I can't get it to jive. Can you help?

```
document.write('<a href=\"\http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/\"\ target=\"\_blank\"\ onClick=\"\trackOutboundLinktarget=(this, 'Outbound Links', 'domain.com'); return false;\"\><img src=\"images/infographic.png\" border=\"0\" class=\"borders\" alt=\"Check out the Infographic\" /></a><br /><br /></center>');
```

I think it has to do with the single quotes around Outbound... but not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you escaping all these other characters: `\h`, `\ `, `\_`, `\t`, `\>`?  The correct escape pattern is `\"`, not `\"\ `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes since the entire string is wrapped in single quotes:

```
'...(this, \'Outbound Links\', \'domain.com\');...'
           ^               ^   ^           ^
```

Technically, escaping the double quotes is not necessary.  You only need to escape quotes that are the same type as the quotes used around the entire string.

Also, it appears you are escaping some strange characters:

```
\"\http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/\"\ target=\"\_blank\"\ 
  ^^ ??                                       ^^ ??      ^^ ??
```

The correct pattern to escape a character, is `\x`, not `\x\`.  Otherwise, the second `\` will get misinterpreted as the start of a second escape sequence.

Comment: Many thanks mellamokb that did the trick. I knew I should have been escaping the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I found all `\` that were too much and the ones missing …

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLinktarget=(this, \'Outbound Links\', \'domain.com\'); return false;"><img src="images/infographic.png" border="0" class="borders" alt="Check out the Infographic" /></a><br /><br /></center>');
```

Comment: You might even remove all escape signs for double quote signs.

Comment: Ah you are right - I overlooked the very first one … Way to much slahses. :)

Comment: +1 The OP is doing some really strange escaping, I wonder if they think the escape pattern is actually `\"\ `?

Comment: Thanks and that's what I though too.

Answer (score 1):

You have the double quotes escaped, but the whole string is inside single quotes. Just change that to double quotes.

Try this:

```
document.write("<a href=\"http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/\" target=\"_blank\" onClick=\"trackOutboundLinktarget=(this, 'Outbound Links', 'domain.com'); return false;\"><img src=\"images/infographic.png\" border=\"0\" class=\"borders\" alt=\"Check out the Infographic\" /></a><br /><br /></center>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to escape all ' or " within the string. It should escape when you are same quota of the string.

Example: 
"I'm a boy"  this string no need to escape
But look at this example:
 'I\'m a boy' this time you have to escape becasue of same quot of string

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/" target="_blank" onClick="trackOutboundLinktarget=(this, \'Outbound Links\', \'domain.com\'); return false;"><img src="images/infographic.png" border="0" class="borders" alt="Check out the Infographic" /></a><br /><br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code..

```
document.write("<a href=\"\http://www.domain.com/drowning-accidents/\"\ target=\"\_blank\"\ onClick=\"\trackOutboundLinktarget=(this, 'Outbound Links', 'domain.com'); return false;\"\><img src=\"images/infographic.png\" border=\"0\" class=\"borders\" alt=\"Check out the Infographic\" /></a><br /><br /></center>");
```

I guess you have used single quotes instead of double quotes.
Check if it works..:)